# Do MongoDB selectors need validation?

Tags: mongodb, security, mongodb-query

I am building a web application where the (untrusted) cient must be able to filter a list of documents in a Mongo collection. Currently the client is supplying a Mongo-selector which is then used on the server side without further validation.

Now I was wondering about two questions:

- Is it dangerous in any way to use an arbitrary, client-supplied selector in a standard Mongo query like this?
  `Collection.find(clientSelector);`
- If I want the client to be able to access only a specific subset of the documents in the collection, and apply its filter on top of that, is it safe to do it like this?
  `Collection.find({ $and: [accessFilter, userFilter] });`
  Here only the `userFilter` is supplied by the client. If one or both of the filters are arrays they get merged into one, otherwise Mongo would complain.

Just to be clear: I don't care if the user is able to "break" the query in a way which would make it invalid. I just want to make sure that the user can't access documents he is not allowed to.

Comment: They could potentialy do an SQL-injection-style attack. Also your bigger risk is DDoS I think. Overall its a bad idea to just inject your client query straight into your DB because maybe there is something that _even the Mongo team_ doesn't know about. If something like that comes out, its going to be a lot easier to deal with it if you have an already existing middle layer

Comment: Can you give an example for the attack? I don't see that vulnerability. DDoS is not really an issue here because the whole thing is behind a limiter.

Comment: I know it's generally a bad idea to use anything from the client directly, but as this is just a `find`, not an `insert`, `update` or `remove`, I thought I could skip the validation. That would not only save me some time but also enable the client to use all the features of the Mongo selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never trust any input from the client because its all untrustworthy. Mongo databases are just as vulnerable attacks as any other database, even if its just a find. For reference, see [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) OWASP article on NOSQL injection attacks.

You mentioned allowing user's to use the full capabilities of Mongo's find operator, and that article shows one reason why its a bad idea: abuse of the `$where` operator. I can now inject

```
$where: function(){while(true{}}
```

1000 times.Good luck preventing that.

And that's just what I can think of as someone with virtually no cybersecurity expertise. Now think about people who actually know what they're doing and maybe have an exploit Mongo doesn't know about.